# Best way to check for NULL value in MySql query

Tags: mysql

Can any one please let me know the best way to use IF statement in mysql query to show if the "email" field is NULL then it should show as "no email"...

```
Postcode    Telephone             Email
----------------------------------------------------------
BS20 0QN    1275373088         no email
BS20 0QN    1275373088         no email
PO9 4HG 023 92474208        prabhu1@vacmedia.com
SO43 7DS    07801 715200       test@vacmedia.com
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the COALESCE function:

```
COALESCE(Email, 'no email')
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this way

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YourColumn IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`IFNULL` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT Postcode, Telephone, IFNULL(Email, "no email")
FROM table
```